# How exactly does Nautilus sort files by name?

Tags: linux, gnome, filenames, sort, nautilus

I noticed that Nautilus(GNOME Files) does not fully sort alphabetically.

```
$ touch 1
$ touch 2
$ touch 3
$ touch '!2'
```

Then the files are displayed in the following order: `!2 1 2 3`. This is fully alphabetically sorted since `!` is smaller than numbers in terms of ASCII code. Let's add a few more files.

```
$ touch a
$ touch b
$ touch c
$ touch '!b'
```

The files are now displayed in the following order: `!2 1 2 3 a !b b c`. Note that `!b` comes before `b` but after `a`, which means the files are not fully alphabetically sorted anymore.

```
$ touch 01
$ touch 02
$ touch 001
$ touch 002
```

`!2 1 01 001 2 02 002 3 a !b b c`. Now this is more confusing as at first numbers seemed to be alphabetically sorted but that theory broke after adding files beginning with zeroes.

Interestingly `ls` disagrees with Nautilus.

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
$ ls
 001   002   01   02   1  '!2'   2   3   a   ab   ac  '!b'   b   ba   c
```

What algorithms are Nautilus and `ls` using here? Debian Stable Gnome Files version 43.2.

Answer (score 2):

By default, 'ls' uses the libc locale-specific sort order, the same as used by 'sort'. For all `*.UTF-8` locales (*except* `C.UTF-8`), Glibc implements the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) (or something [close to it](https://superuser.com/a/228232)) adapted to the current locale.

(For example, see the 'LC_COLLATE' section of [localedata/locales/es_ES](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/es_ES#l53).)

Compare the output of `ls` against `LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 ls` (or just `LC_COLLATE=C ls`).

Nautilus uses an algorithm which is centered around [g_utf8_collate_key_for_filename()](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.utf8_collate_key_for_filename.html) provided by GLib2. This is also locale-based but additionally provides 'natural' sorting of numbers; the source code has an [explanation](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/af30e69140c712f20a8b6dda9d046c4b5b1fe092/glib/gunicollate.c#L524-L568) of how it works.

(Nautilus also has [additional code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/blob/f542b7fc8462a3d0689d96ebb140f331feb43ba0/src/nautilus-file.c#L3262-3293) to always order dotfiles and backupfiles (i.e. `.*` and `#*`) after non-dotfiles, which takes priority over the collation key.)

GNU 'ls' has the `-v` option for "natural (version)" sort, which handles numbers more like Nautilus (but always uses ASCII order instead of locale order). Similarly, 'sort' has `-V`.

> This is fully alphabetically sorted since ! is smaller than numbers in terms of ASCII code

This does not follow. Ordering in terms of ASCII code **is not** "alphabetical sort". At best, it is *asciibetical* sort. (Consider yourself lucky IBM did not use EBCDIC for its PCs…)

For one, ASCII orders `Z` before `a`, which is distinctly non-alphabetical even in English. (Locale-aware sorting in both cases above will use `AaBbCc..` while forcing ASCII order by specifying C or C.UTF-8 as the locale will give you `ABC..Zabc..`.)

It also only covers the English alphabet; my own name contains alphabetic characters that are not in ASCII – "alphabetical sort by ASCII order" is an undefined operation on them, and even sorting them by Unicode codepoint order would result in an order that is not alphabetical to anyone who speaks the language. (The correct order would be U+0065 < U+0117 < U+0066.) Remember the 'A' in 'ASCII' stands for 'American', not 'Alphabetic'.

On the other hand, the ASCII order includes characters that are not actually part of an alphabet and therefore would have no weight in an alphabetical order:

> Note that `!b` comes before `b` but after `a`, which means the files are not fully alphabetically sorted anymore.

They are exactly alphabetically sorted, because `!` is not an alphabet character, therefore both `b` and `!b` have equal weight.